# how to return with if and switch statements in function body

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a Java code with the following pattern:

```
enum Foo
{
    ORANGE, APPLE, BANANA
}

Foo bar()
{
    switch(calcValue())
    {
        case "orange": return ORANGE;
        case "apple": return APPLE;
        case "banana": return BANANA;
    }
}
```

The design of `calcValue` method ensures it never returns *anything else than the three strings that the switch statement checks.* If it would not be able to return either of the three strings, it throws an exception. This implies that the missing `default` keyword may be unnecessary and the default switch behavior is never triggered, hence `default` is omitted. However, Java naturally (and rightfully so, in general) complains that `bar` must (always) return a value. I was thinking to throw an exception as default, but as mentioned `calcValue` throws one already. I am primarily after a simple and efficient (involving least runtime checks and code) design to solve this little problem - I don't want to throw two exceptions, and `calcValue` is not under my control, so I cannot do anything with it.

I hope I have explained myself well here, if not, I will do my best to try to clarify. In essence, this is about designing methods with value where switch defaults are known to not apply. That may also apply to `if-then-else-if-then-else-...-then-else` statement patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

> The design of calcValue method ensures it never returns anything else than the three strings that the switch statement checks.

However, this contract is not expressed by the signature of `calcValue`; it just returns a string and the type checker of Java has no way to know that only *some* strings are possible. I'd consider this a flaw in the API of the `calcValue` function.

The bottom line is that Java is correct - you *do* lack a `default` case, since your assumption about the inner workings of `calcValue` is not enforced by the type system, so it may change at any point without the compiler noticing.

Comment: You have a very very good point with the last paragraph. That is the most convincing argument so far, for adding a default case.

Answer (score 1):

Long if/then/else and switch statements are a bad sign, in my opinion.  I prefer writing in an object-oriented style whenever I can.

Like using a Map, passing in the key, and returning the value.

Your simple example could and should be an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `calcValue()` throws an error for the default case, that is a logical conclusion and Java compiler wouldn't understand that and so is complaining about a code path without a return. You HAVE to throw an exception from this method as well for the default case.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for good reason; since you don't control calcValue(), you should have code to handle future changes.

But, if you want to continue as above, change the last case to default so that it always returns "BANANA" in the absence of ORANGE or APPLE.

Comment: I decided to throw an exception, just in case. I like the fail-soon strategy, that way I at least know something went wrong (even though my `calcValue` pretty much ensures the opposite). If 'BANANA' maps both oranges and bananas, that sounds like a longer debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> calcValue is not under my control

Then, you should not depend on it that it'll always `throw` an exception.

You should add `default` to your `switch` construct and should throw exception if control reaches there.

Another point is that your `bar()` method should be complete in itself.

You are trying to make it tightly coupled with `calcValue()`. The signature contract of `Bar()` says that it'll always return a `Foo` but instead of doing that you are depending on `calcValue()` to implement the contract; and that's wrong.

Comment: Even though it is not under my control, it is defined with a "...throws NoSuchElementException" clause.

Comment: Ok, but it may change in future.

Comment: Well, in that case I hope its signature, with a `throws` clause, will not.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering the question, but maybe it would simplify things to use `Enum.valueOf()`. If `calcValue()` is guaranteed to return one of those three values, you could just do:

```
enum Foo { ORANGE, APPLE, BANANA }

Foo bar() { return Foo.valueOf(calcValue().toUpperCase()); }
```

And delegate the decision to `Enum.valueOf`, which, by the way, throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if there's no such element.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to have the enum know how to translate itself properly

```
public enum Foo {
    BANANA("banana"),
    ORANGE("orange"),
    APPLE("apple");

private String calculationCode;

private Foo(String calculationCode) {
    this.calculationCode=calculationCode;
}

public static Foo byCalculationCode(String code) {
    for (Foo foo : values()) {
        if (foo.calculationCode.equals(code)) {
            return foo;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Unknown code:" + code);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. This is a solution involving a second `throw` statement, which was what I originally were trying to avoid. In case I cannot, I prefer `switch`. This is too "runtime" for my tastes ;-) I flagged your answer as useful though. I also have to keep enumeration constants detached from potential values. In my real code the enumeration does not carry purpose, it's merely an enumeration.The users of enumeration class will try to fetch its values based on different key names, even for one and the same constant, hence enumeration values are of no big use to me.